# Responsive button script and data-toggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and what I am trying to do is open a datepicker with a button. However I want to open the datepicker normally as a pop-up when the screen is over 992px BUT if the screen size is under 992px open the datepicker inside a modal pop-up.

```
<div class="open-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datepickerModal">
```

Using the above code whatever screen size the browser opens up to initially makes the button behavior 'stick'. If I open it in a window larger than 992px it opens as a pop-up but if I shrink the window under 992px the modal open won't work. If I open the window under 992px the modal will work but not the pop-up if I expand the window size.

I think the solution is probably to switch classes via script depending on the window width (so that the button does not share functions) but not sure how to do that with the data-toggle attribute.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resize trigger in jquery if you need to capture window resize:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   if($( window ).width() >= 992){
       $(".open-button").data("toggle","modal");
   }else{
       $(".open-button").data("toggle","nonmodal");
});
```

Please check if modal and nonmodal are well set since I couldnt figure out when you want modal or not

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But I think I figured it out this way:

```
    var boxW = $(window).innerWidth(); // FIND THE BROWSER WINDOW WIDTH
    if(boxW > 992){ 
        $('#arrive-button').removeAttr('data-toggle');
        $('#arrive-button').removeAttr('data-target');
        $('#depart-button').removeAttr('data-toggle');
        $('#depart-button').removeAttr('data-target');
        $('#arrive-button').addClass('open-button');
        $('#depart-button').addClass('open-button');
    } else { // MOBILE
        $('#arrive-button').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $('#arrive-button').attr('data-target', '#datepickerModal');
        $('#depart-button').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $('#depart-button').attr('data-target', '#datepickerModal');
        $('#arrive-button').removeClass('open-button');
        $('#depart-button').removeClass('open-button');
    }
```

Don't know if doing the data-target is overkill. Didn't know about about 'data-toggle' being an attribute. Duh.